# Looking for a YA. novel about a rural kid who contacts aliens

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I read this back in the late 90s or early 2000s. Reasonably certain the kid's name was Barney, which I thought was funny because the only other Barneys I knew of were "the Dinosaur" and "Rubble". I think the name "Barney" was in the title as well.

Story details I remember:

1. The aliens communicate with tachyons, and the kid manages to intercept a signal somehow.
2. At one point, the alien demonstrates magnetic telekinesis technology by disassembling and reassembling a barn. (Might have occurred in a sequel?)

Comment: Could it be these? http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?7863

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Could this be [*Barney and the UFO*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?914753) (1979) by Margaret Goff Clark?  It's the first of [three books](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?22361) with the same protagonist.  (The others are *Barney in Space* and *Barney on Mars*.)

I don't recall tachyons, but there is an scene where the barn gets partially disassembled (or at least stripped down to its frame):

> As if in slow motion, the scene began to change.  The walls of the barn fell away.  The roof boards sailed out like glider planes and clattered to the grass on either side of the crumbling building.
>
> At the same time the air was filled with a cloud of small flying objects.  At first Barney thought they were bats, but when they, too, rained to the ground, he knew they must be shingles.
>
> In two or three minutes only the framework remained standing.  Under the white light of the stars stood a skeleton barn.

Barney's friend Dick figures out that the effect that took down the barn must have been magnetic in nature, since it removed all the nails, and didn't affect the framework which was pegged together.

[image: Cover of "Barney and the UFO" showing Barney in green pajamas, standing on a roof, looking at a shiny spherical floating ball]